# Reference for a transformation

Tags: reference-request, information-theory, ergodic-theory, entropy

Has the (Lebesgue-)ergodic transformation $T: \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}} \to  \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ defined by $T(x(0)x(1)x(2)\cdots) = x(1)x(3)x(5)\cdots$ been well-studied? If so, where? Does it have a name?

Comment: I don't know if it has but it doesn't look very tough: it seems to be that $\,T\,$ is surjective, not injective...

Comment: What kind of study are you expecting? I mean, what is there to say about this function?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan $T$ is (Lebesgue) measure-preserving, so I'm interested in it's ergodic & information theoretic properties (whence the tags).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan It's also ergodic (wrt the Lebesgue---or uniform---measure) by Kolmogorov's 0-1 law. My point is that it seems like something that must've been well studied, but I cannot find it.